# Fluid resize except first div

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox, resize

I would like to be able to expand/reset on click the width of a selected flexed div.

My main concern is that I want all the other divs to also resize in real time, accordingly, to fit the remaining space.

All of them **BUT** the first div, which I want to always have a fixed width and never resize.

That last part is the problem I want to address.

The only way I could do this is this way:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="divFixed">Fixed</div>

    <div class="data">

        <div class="divFluid">Fluid</div>
        <div class="divFluid">Fluid</div>
        <div class="divFluid">Fluid</div>

    </div>

</div>

<button>Expand</button>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.divFixed{
    width:50px; /* fixed */
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.data{
    width: calc( 100% - 51px );
    float:left;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.divFluid{
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: width 1s;
}

.divFluid:last-child{
    border-right: 0px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var clickStatus=0;

$(document).on('click','button',function(e){
    if(clickStatus==0){
        $('.divFluid:nth-child(1)').css('width','300%');
        $('button').html('Reset');
        clickStatus=1;
    }
    else{
        $('.divFluid:nth-child(1)').css('width','100%');
        $('button').html('Expand');
        clickStatus=0;
    }   
})
```

Here is the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lh5pnrcm/

The example is pretty clear and perfectly showcases what I want to achieve. So this works fine but it doesn't suit my needs as I need the first div not to be structurally isolated. It is a bit long to explain but isolating it in the HTML makes it very hard for me to implement other features that aren't addressed here.

In other words, I need the HTML to be like this, while achieving the **EXACT** same result showed in the jsfiddle:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="div">Fixed</div>
    <div class="div">Fluid</div>
    <div class="div">Fluid</div>
    <div class="div">Fluid</div>

</div>

<button>Expand</button>
```

So do you think it is possible to discriminate the first div while using flex without isolating it from the rest of the divs in the HTML (and without using a table)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have to be more specific, cause I just changed HTML to what you want, adjust JS selector and add `min-width` instead of `width` to CSS and it works:

```js
var clickStatus = 0;

$(document).on("click", "button", function(e) {
  if (clickStatus == 0) {
    $(".divFluid")
      .first()
      .css("width", "300%");
    $("button").html("Reset");
    clickStatus = 1;
  } else {
    $(".divFluid")
      .first()
      .css("width", "100%");
    $("button").html("Expand");
    clickStatus = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.divFixed {
    min-width: 50px; /* fixed width */
    background: #999;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.data {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background: #555;
}

.divFluid {
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: width 1s;
}

.divFluid:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
}

button {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="data">
        <div class="divFixed">Fixed</div>
        <div class="divFluid">Fluid</div>
        <div class="divFluid">Fluid</div>
        <div class="divFluid">Fluid</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button>Expand</button>
```

I also cleaned it a bit and got rid of any `float`. You can't mix floated elements with Flex.

Comment: Thank you very much. For the life of me, I just can't see the mistake I made because I tried what you did before with no success. Even now when editing my code according to your changes. It only works when I copy/paste your script. Go figure. I probably missed something minor that I can't see.
Anyway, it's working and I thank you very much for that.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri  your code already shows you are close to that... which confused me on what's really the expected result  :)

Comment: @BachirMessaouri I had this many times and it always is some typo in the code. Glad I could help :)